# JQuery Not Changing Select Box Option

Tags: jquery, html, select

I have the following jquery code to change my selected select box option.

```
   $(function () {

      var prev_id = -1;          
      $('.color_opt').click(function() { 
        if (prev_id != -1)
        {
          $("#"+prev_id).removeClass('opt_sel');
        }
        var current_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var current_color = $(this).data('color');
        $("#product-select-option-0[value=" + current_color +"]").prop("selected","selected") ;
        $("#product-select[value=" + current_id +"]").prop("selected","selected") ;

        $(this).addClass('opt_sel');
        prev_id = current_id;
      });


    });
```

This is my html

```
<div id="original_selector" class="select clearfix">
            <div class="selector-wrapper">
                <label>Color</label>
                <select id="product-select-option-0" data-option="option1" class="single-option-selector">
                    <option value="Red">Red</option>
                    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
                    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <select id="product-select" name="id" style="display:none">
              <option value="849558613">Red - $29.99</option>            
              <option value="849558617">Blue - $24.99</option>             
              <option value="849558621">Orange - $29.99</option>             
            </select>
        </div>
```

Everything seems to be executing fine, as the selected class is changing onclick although the value of the select box is not changing for either boxes. The current_id and current_color are being passed just fine as I've checked through an alert.

Any ideas as to why my select box options are not changing?

Comment: I'm not seeing `color_opt` anywhere in your HTML?

Comment: 19 gold badges and this question?!

Comment: @doniyor, 19 famous questions :-)

Comment: @WojciechFrącz asking so many famous questions is not easy, man

Comment: @doniyor I try ;) and I left the color_opt part out it wasn't relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `prop` to select the desired value. Use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead.

```
$(function () {
  var prev_id = -1;          
  $('.color_opt').click(function() { 
    if (prev_id != -1)
    {
      $("#"+prev_id).removeClass('opt_sel');
    }
    var current_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var current_color = $(this).data('color');
    $("#product-select-option-0").val(current_color);
    $("#product-select").val(current_id);

    $(this).addClass('opt_sel');
    prev_id = current_id;
  });
});
```

When you use `prop`, multiple options might gain the `selected` attribute. What the browser will show as the selected value is unpredictable then.

Comment: If there is other javascript being executed for when the value changes will this trigger that?

Comment: Hmm doesn't appear to be triggering the other jquery but it's better than what I had. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Dont worry about setting 'selected' attribute instead you can just select the values using following

```
$("#product-select-option-0").val(current_color);
$("#product-select").val(current_id);
```